# Persisting DOM changes after clicking a link and then pressing the Back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using jQuery's appendTo() method to append items to an unordered list. When the user clicks another link, and then presses the Back button, the appended items disappear. Is there a way to persist those changes using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your user navigates away from your page, the DOM is discarded. When your user hits the back button, they get a fresh copy of the HTML from your server (or from their cache).

So, you have one of 2 options:

1. The correct way would be to save the DOM state in a cookie (or session), and then on page load check if that cookie is present, and if so, append that info.
2. Since you have not provided enough information, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. So, if a cookie is not good enough, you might have to attach a click event to the link, and instead of just sending them off to that link, you'll first store the DOM in a variable `var theDOM = $('html').clone(true);`, and then load in the HTML for that link with an AJAX request.

You'll also have to inform the browser that your history state has changed. That can be accomplished with HTML5's new History API. In older browsers you can do something similar via the hash part of the URL (although in older versions of IE even that won't work). Then, when the user clicks the back button, you'll reload that DOM from your variable...

Either way, this is WAY too complicated. You're probably looking at this the wrong way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to achieve what SO or Facebook already does, adding comments without reloading the page. The comment is already saved in the database, so should I be forcing page reload after Back button is pressed?

Comment: I just checked here, and the same issue happens in SO too, so maybe this is a problem I shouldn't fix? Just to clarify, add a comment on this question, navigate to another page, press Back button. The comment will be gone. Pressing F5 will refresh the page with the comment, though.

Comment: It all depends on your app. If the updated info is mission critical, then yes, you should force a page refresh (or use an AJAX request to only get the data needed). But most of the time, this is just the way the web works. Users are pretty much accustomed to this sort of behaviour...

Answer (score 4):

When hitting BACK, some browsers cache te previous (originally loaded) page. If you can regenerate the page with a fresh reload you can use cache-control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' to force this on a BACK.

Chrome wants no-store, and IE wants must-revalidate. For other browsers (and w3c) no-cache is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any problem to use `iframe` then you can use it to preserve the previous data. On `iframe` load event write a js code which will take the preserved data within it and append it to desired element. This way when you navigate to next page and press back button the iframe will load and then the load event handler will do its job,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think iframe will complicate things further. I think this is actually a common (and possibly not very important) issue - see my comment on the previous answer.

Comment: The other alternative is to make a ajax call on page load and fetch only the required data.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good suggestion, too. I have to check which events are fired when user presses the Back button. Do you know if $(document).ready() is fired?