# Text shows then disappears on page reload; javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to show text on button click. When I click the button, the text appears then disappears in a flash after page reload.

This is the paragraph that contains the text after clicking the button

```
<p class="lead" id="class"><strong style="color: red; font-size: 15px; display: none;"></strong></p>
```

This is my button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
```

This is my script

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("class").innerHTML = "Class current balance total";

        }
</script>
```

How can I make the text show and not disappear after page refresh?

PS : I am very new to javascript.

Comment: Short answer: you can't easily do that. Longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058634/persisting-dom-changes-after-clicking-a-link-and-then-pressing-the-back-button). Refresh means exactly that: it wipes the slate clean.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. I put it in a Plunker and there doesn't seem to be an issue. https://plnkr.co/edit/v0RKTBjk5QBN5JL5oNPl?p=preview (As a side note, don't use `id='class'`. It might be hard to tell your `id` different from the `class` attribute). **EDIT** If you meant that your text disappears after you reload the page, that's what it's supposed to do. You don't want your text staying around for other people to see.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want the text to go away after a refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that local storage would help with this problem. I have implemented a solution here for you. Local storage allows web applications to store locally within the user's browser. It is different than cookies. What I have done here is stored your text into local storage as a key/value pair. Local storage retrieves it using the "getItem" method. You can see a demo of this code [here](https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/zEPJGR?editors=1111)

The code:

```
<script>
  //an immediately invoked function that checks to see if the text is in local storage already
  (function(){
    //if the text is in local storage, set the html
    if (localStorage.currentTotal){
    console.log(localStorage.currentTotal);
    document.getElementById('class').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("currentTotal");
  }
    })();
  //function that gets called for an onclick event
  function myFunction() {
// Store in local storage
localStorage.setItem("currentTotal", "Class current balance total");
//set the inner html to what is in local storage
document.getElementById("class").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("currentTotal");

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because of `type="submit"`... try `<input type="button" ... />` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with this way. That's not how JS works. In order to keep the data back to the state it was, even after refreshing the page, you need to do that with Localstorage.

Localstorage is a concept in JS, while you are displaying the data after the event happen, you are storing the value in your browser's localstorage, so since the value is already stored in browser, you should be able to retrieve that value.

it shud be something like this localstorage.setItem to save the value and localstorage.getItem to access the saved value and display it on your page.

Hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

The form tag is causing a page reload. Remove the form tags and it should work fine.

Comment: What `<form>` tag?

Comment: The only reason why the page would reload is if it is trying to submit a form. Other then that, you are pressing reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing display:none to display:block in your script.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("class").innerHTML = "Class current balance total";
    document.getElementById("class").children.style.display = 'block';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

issue with input value is on refresh it disappears,localstorage does not work,but you can get it to work,do setItem code,and getItem but have window.onload and inside document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =localStorage.getItem("peanuts");you see localStorage has stored info but to display you need to retrieve it,f12 to check its stored,also i add if(typeof(Storage) !== etc., to my code when using localStorage